# Export all SSIS packages from SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export

We have quite a few SSIS packages on SQL Server 2012 deployed to SSISDB, you can right-click on a project and select 'Export' saved as an *ispac file, however, is there a script to Export All Projects to *.ispac?  A script that will loop through all projects and export the *.ispac files to a directory?

Much appreciated.

Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You can find Import/Export folders and projects from/to local file system to/from SSIS catalog using PowerShell on TechNet and [download CatalogMigration](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ImportExport-projects-bca5f29f) file

I hope this will help you

Comment: The link "download CatalogMigration" did not go to any resource to help with this. Does anyone have the powershell code to do this?